# three mutually independent events and minimum/maximum value of B given A

Tags: probability

I cannot seem to solve a and d.

Let A and B and C be three events with P(A) = 0.9 and P(B) = 0.5 and P(C) = 0.1. Answer the following questions.

**a.    What is P(A ∩ B  ∩ C) if all events are mutually independent?**

condition 1: P(A ∩ B ∩ C) = P(A)P(B)P(C), 0.9 * 0.5 * 0.1 = 0.045

```
         P(A or B) = 0.9 + 0.5 - P(A ∩ B)
         P(A or B) = 1.4 - P(A ∩ B)
```

condition 2: P(A ∩ B)= P(A) * P(B), 0.9 * 0.5 = 0.45

```
               P(A ∩ C) = P(A) * P(C), 0.9 * 0.1 = 0.9
               P(B ∩ C) = P(B) * P(C), 0.5 * 0.1 = 0.5
```

**b.    What is P(A or B) if P(A|B) = 0.5?**

P(A|B) = P(A ∩ B)/P(B)
P(A ∩ B) = 0.25
P(A or B) = P(A) + P(B) – P(A and B)
P(A or B) = 1.15

**c.    Can events A and C be both mutually exclusive and exhaustive?**

P(A) + P(C) = 1

0.9 + 0.1 = 1 (events are mutually exhaustive and exclusive)

**d.    What are the minimum and maximum value of P(B|A)?**

Comment: Can you think of any reason why $P(A\cap B)$ cannot be smaller than $0.4$?  No? Do you know a formula for $P(A\cup B)$ when $A$ and $B$ are not necessarily mutually exclusive?

Comment: For (a) your "condition 1" seems to answer the question

Comment: For (b) you seem to have a probability greater than $1$ which cannot be correct

Comment: For (d) $P(B \mid A)=\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(A)}$ so you need to start by finding the minimum and maximum values of $ P(A\cap B)$

Answer (score 1):

An intuitive solution to d). The maximum value of $P(B|A)$ is when $%
B\rightarrow A$. Then $B$ will happen $5$ out of $9$ times $A$ happens, i.e.
$P(B|A)=5/9$. The minimum value is reached when $notB\rightarrow A$. Then $B$
will happen $4$ out of $9$ times $A$ happens, i.e. $P(B|A)=4/9$.

PS: the title is misleading since the events are not mutually independent in general.